# Javascript: Properly Globalizing a Websocket Send Function

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am working with a WebSocket and trying to be able to send socket data at anytime from throughout my application. When I attempt to access the send command from within another function, I am receiving:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

This only is occuring when I call a function, this is how I am setting up my websocket:

```
Main.socket = (function() {
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://server:port");

socket.onopen = function() {  
    console.log("Socket has been opened!");  
}

function send() {
    socket.send('test');
}

return {
    socket: socket,
    send: send
}
})();
```

I am able to call the function globally, and also when I console.log Main.socket from within a function it is able to see the socket. But when I call the send function I get that error.

Comment: I suspect it is because the socket has not been *opened* yet - has `onopen` been called? "An attempt was made to use an [Socket] object that is not, or is no longer, usable [because it is in an Invalid State]."

Comment: The socket is opened, if I open my console and do Main.socket.send('test'); I am able to see that come through on my server, but when I try to call from within a function it fails. I have added an init function to my Main socket that I call at the start.

Comment: If you open the main console and call Main.socket.send, time has *already* elapsed - and time enough such that socket likely has had ample time to open (also, importantly, the JavaScript code has been idle such that events have been processed). Try this, *from the failing code*: call the `send` in a `setTimeout(function () { Main.socket.send("yay") }, 500)`. Of course this is a silly amount of time to wait, in reality we should only wait until `onopen` is triggered. Using futures can make this chaining easy, but it *will* require asynchronous usage in the consumer.

Comment: Ah! That did the trick, so I guess I'll edit my Main.init to have a delay so the websocket has time to connect. Thanks!

Comment: No, no, that's just an ugly hack. Utilize the onopen callback and expose your own asynchronous binding. If you are using jQuery 1.8+, [$.Defered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which creates a Promise/A object is handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the socket has *not* been opened yet. `WebSocket.send` *cannot* be used until the *asynchronous* `onopen` event occurs.

While using `setTimeout` (for a long enough duration) "should work", the correct way to deal with asynchronous JavaScript programming is to treat program flow as a sequence of dependent events.

In any case, here is a small example showing how to use a [jQuery Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which (as of jQuery 1.8 isn't broken and honors the [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) contract):

```
Main.socket = (function($) {
   var socket = new WebSocket("ws://server:port");
   // Promise will be called with one argument, the "send" function for this
   // socket.
   var readyPromise = $.Deferred();
   socket.onopen = function() {
     console.log("Socket has been opened!");
     readyPromise.resolve(socket.send)
  }
  return readyPromise;
})(jQuery);
```

Then later, in the code that uses this little module:

```
Main.socket.then(function (send) {
   // This will only be called after `Promise.resolve` is called in the module
   // which will be called in the `WebSocket.onopen` callback.
   send("Hello world!");
})
// This code may or may not execute before the `then` function above
// depending upon the state the Promise/Deferred Object.
// However, we can get consistent program flow by using `then`-chaining
// of promises.
```

Of course you don't have to use Promises - callbacks will work just fine, although I prefer the unified contract/framework of Promises - and you can use whatever names or structure is most fitting.

Also, note that it *might not be good* to have a single WebSocket for the entire page lifecycle as this won't correctly handle disconnect and recovery scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative solution to waiting for the web socket connection to come online, replace your call to :

```
function send() {
    web_socket.send('test');
}
```

with this :

```
function send(msg) {

    wait_for_socket_connection(socket, function() {
        socket.send(msg);
    });
};

function wait_for_socket_connection(socket, callback){

    setTimeout(
        function(){
            if (socket.readyState === 1) {
                if(callback !== undefined){
                    callback();
                }
                return;

            } else {

                console.log("... waiting for web socket connection to come online");

                wait_for_socket_connection(socket,callback);
            }
        }, 5);
};
```